# How to call jQuery function inside Handlebar script (template) tag?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ember.js

Handlebar Script tag is :

```
<section class="listtext">
    <div class="container">
        <p class="test">hello</p>
     <div>
</section>
```

My jQuery is of type:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("p").click(function(){
        alert("Alert clicked.");
    });
});
```

Please help to run this jQuery inside the script tag in handle bar.

Answer (score 0):

You can define a component:

**/templates/components/my-hello.hbs**

```
<section class="listtext">
    <div class="container">
        <p class="test">hello</p>
     <div>
</section>
```

**/components/my-hello.js**

```
import Ember from 'ember';
export default Ember.Component.extend({

    didInsertElement () {
        this.$("p").click(function(){
            alert("Alert clicked.");
        });
    }

});
```

After that, whenever you insert this component. the jQuery snippet would be executed in the scope of component's root element.

**Update**

If you don't want to use Ember, the only way I see is to use dom selectors:

```
    $("body").on("click", ".listtext p", function(){
        alert("Alert clicked.");
    });
```

Comment: thanks for your response @a.smirnov...is there any way to do it without using ember.

Comment: Edited an answer according to your request.

Answer (score 0):

you have to put your jQuery Code into a component like smirnov suggested or into the site views didInsertElement hook- but views are deprecated since ember 1.13.8.

So i suggest you to use the provided solution from smirnov! :-)

best regards